# Test States Language Specification in a Step Function's state machine

Tags: aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

We have a Step Function-state machine which has States Language Specification written in json format that calls multiple Lambda functions based on input and condition during the execution of the workflow.

Is there a way to unit/integration test this json code (workflow) by mocking the Lambda dependencies? For ex. Test when a specific Lambda's output is XXX then YYY step gets called by the step function workflow.

I checked ["Develop and Test AWS Step Functions Workflows Locally"](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/02/develop-and-test-aws-step-functions-workflows-locally/) doc but it seems to provide a way for testing Lambda's in a step function locally. What I want is to mock the Lambda and test the json (workflow/States Language).

Answer (score 1):

We had a developer want to run lambda functions locally and test in this manor as well. I honestly think this is pretty useless and doesn't add any value, the reason why is that you aren't testing anything other than your own understanding of States Language Specification.

Say you write a test for some job throwing an exception:

```
    "Try": {
      "Next": "Job Succeeded",
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [{
        "StartAt": "TODO",
        "States": {
        "TODO": {
          "Comment": "This throws an exception.",
          "Type": "Task",
          Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.waitForTaskToken",
          "Parameters": {
            "Input": {
              "something.$": "$$.Execution.Input.something"
            }
          },
          "End": true
        }
        }
      "Catch": [{
        "ErrorEquals": ["States.ALL"],
        "Next": "Job Failed"
      }]
    }
```

And test when `TODO` fails it goes to `Job Failed` & when it succeeds it goes to `Job Succeeded`. Well this will definitely happen, there is no need to test this, unless you are working for AWS yourself.

The only real tests worth doing are integration tests and performance testing. You could simulate a service going down, database turning off etc. starting a step function, and get the result. Even then though if you know what your tasks will return back to the function integration tests won't give you much.

What I would suggest is focusing your testing effort on performance testing the step functions, this will show if you start having issues in your system, if the step function start timing out etc. But unit testing a step function won't tell you anything you don't already know. That's kind of the whole point with step functions.